# prevent users from downloading html site text

Tags: html

Id like to know if its possible to prevent users from downloading html text from a site.
Right now, my plan is to run over a DB and create pictures from the text and display that on the site, however, as you can imagine, that takes time, and loads of resources.

I don't necessarily want to disable right click unless there is no alternative.
A good example of this would be http://www.wolframalpha.com/, however, even they create images, and one can simply right click and 'save as'.
The idea is primarily to prevent bots for performing a mass search and download.

If anyone could steer me in the correct direction, id really appreciate it :)

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever you display on your website can be "downloaded". In fact, for the browser to display it it *has* to be downloaded onto the client's computer. You cannot not download something yet display it. Whatever you put publicly on your website is public, period. No way around it. The only useful approach here would be to track client behaviour, e.g. if the same client is requesting lots of pages in a short amount of time, it may be a bot. But there are ways around that too, e.g. just query slower.

Comment: This isn't helpful and really degrades the usability / performance of a site. Just think of people using a screen reader and stuff like that.

Comment: The standard mechanisms used by major content providers include: 1) Sue users 2) Ship own hardware. They wouldn't spend so much money if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Whatever happens to end up in the client's browser is *already* downloaded. You can't prevent the user to save it on his computer. Even if you were to convert your text to an image, you can't prevent the client to use an OCR software to retrieve the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want something to be downloaded, just don't put it publicly on a website. Putting your text on an image or blocking right click is ridiculous, doesn't prevent anything and breaks the usability.

And all bots aren't evil. Think about Google bot (don't you want your website to be on Google ?), or about bots used by blind people to be able to read the text ...

Comment: Screen readers are not bots (although they do depend on text being text). Bots are programs that crawl automatically, not which are under manual control of a user.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake because both are synonyms in my native language. But that's not really important here, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you disable right click still anyone can download the HTML code of the side and the text inside html tags. There is no point of doing that. 
The Images also can be downloaded even if you disable right click.

But you can put your images in a flash presentation where will be more difficult for someone to extract each photo. I think this is the only solution to your problem.